# Why use separable convolutions on one channel input?

Tags: machine-learning, word-embeddings, convolution

I'm currently working on the [Text Classification Guide](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification/) from Google.
During step 4, they create a `CNN` with separable convolutions for use with word embeddings:

```py
    def sepcnn_model(blocks,
                 filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 embedding_dim,
                 dropout_rate,
                 pool_size,
                 input_shape,
                 num_classes,
                 num_features,
                 use_pretrained_embedding=False,
                 is_embedding_trainable=False,
                 embedding_matrix=None):
    """Creates an instance of a separable CNN model.

    # Arguments
        blocks: int, number of pairs of sepCNN and pooling blocks in the model.
        filters: int, output dimension of the layers.
        kernel_size: int, length of the convolution window.
        embedding_dim: int, dimension of the embedding vectors.
        dropout_rate: float, percentage of input to drop at Dropout layers.
        pool_size: int, factor by which to downscale input at MaxPooling layer.
        input_shape: tuple, shape of input to the model.
        num_classes: int, number of output classes.
        num_features: int, number of words (embedding input dimension).
        use_pretrained_embedding: bool, true if pre-trained embedding is on.
        is_embedding_trainable: bool, true if embedding layer is trainable.
        embedding_matrix: dict, dictionary with embedding coefficients.

    # Returns
        A sepCNN model instance.
    """
    op_units, op_activation = _get_last_layer_units_and_activation(num_classes)
    model = models.Sequential()

    # Add embedding layer. If pre-trained embedding is used add weights to the
    # embeddings layer and set trainable to input is_embedding_trainable flag.
    if use_pretrained_embedding:
        model.add(Embedding(input_dim=num_features,
                            output_dim=embedding_dim,
                            input_length=input_shape[0],
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            trainable=is_embedding_trainable))
    else:
        model.add(Embedding(input_dim=num_features,
                            output_dim=embedding_dim,
                            input_length=input_shape[0]))

    for _ in range(blocks-1):
        model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_rate))
        model.add(SeparableConv1D(filters=filters,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  depthwise_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same'))
        model.add(SeparableConv1D(filters=filters,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  depthwise_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same'))
        model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size))

    model.add(SeparableConv1D(filters=filters * 2,
                              kernel_size=kernel_size,
                              activation='relu',
                              bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                              depthwise_initializer='random_uniform',
                              padding='same'))
    model.add(SeparableConv1D(filters=filters * 2,
                              kernel_size=kernel_size,
                              activation='relu',
                              bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                              depthwise_initializer='random_uniform',
                              padding='same'))
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
    model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(op_units, activation=op_activation))
    return model
```

However, looking at the GitHub repo, they only use one channel word embeddings as input:

```py
    def _get_embedding_matrix(word_index, embedding_data_dir, embedding_dim):
    """Gets embedding matrix from the embedding index data.
    # Arguments
        word_index: dict, word to index map that was generated from the data.
        embedding_data_dir: string, path to the pre-training embeddings.
        embedding_dim: int, dimension of the embedding vectors.
    # Returns
        dict, word vectors for words in word_index from pre-trained embedding.
    # References:
        https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/
        Download and uncompress archive from:
        http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip
    """

    # Read the pre-trained embedding file and get word to word vector mappings.
    embedding_matrix_all = {}

    # We are using 200d GloVe embeddings.
    fname = os.path.join(embedding_data_dir, 'glove.6B.200d.txt')
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:  # Every line contains word followed by the vector value
            values = line.split()
            word = values[0]
            coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
            embedding_matrix_all[word] = coefs

    # Prepare embedding matrix with just the words in our word_index dictionary
    num_words = min(len(word_index) + 1, TOP_K)
    embedding_matrix = np.zeros((num_words, embedding_dim))

    for word, i in word_index.items():
        if i >= TOP_K:
            continue
        embedding_vector = embedding_matrix_all.get(word)
        if embedding_vector is not None:
            # words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
            embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
    return embedding_matrix
```

My question is: Why do they use a `SeparableConv1D` layer as their *first* `Convolution` if the embedding layer only has one channel. From my understanding, separable convolutions only give computational benefits compared to normal convolutions when applied to multiple channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `SeparableConv` layer is theoretically identical to `Conv` if the input channel is 1. So, you are right. I think the reason why it is done in this way is only for program convenience. Notice there is a `for _ in range(blocks-1):` loop warpping those `SeparableConv1D & MaxPooling1D` blocks. The speed advantage of using `SeparableConv` starts from the second iteration.